# Regex - how to exclude everything after a capture

Tags: regex, pcre

I have some IIS logs in which I'm looking to extract the file path and file name from the cs_uri_stem field. An example IIS event is as follows:

```
2018-02-21 04:39:13 <IPv4> GET /www/images/flash_email_large.gif - 8030 - <IPv4> Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+.NET4.0E;+.NET4.0C;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Microsoft+Outlook+16.0.4654;+ms-office;+MSOffice+16) 200 0 0 531
```

My regex is as follows:

```
.*?(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PROPFIND)\s(?P<file_path>(?:[^\/]*\/)*)(?P<file_name>.*)\s-
```

but I'm getting extra characters after the file name (in this case, flash_email_large.gif). How can I exclude everything after the file name in my regex?

Thx

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.*` before `\s-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this better performing regex to capture file path and file name in 2 capturing groups:

```
\s(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PROPFIND)\s(?P<file_path>\S*\/)(?P<file_name>\S+)\s-
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjcE4g/1)

**Changes:**

1. Replace starting `.*?` with `\s`
2. Avoid nested quantifier expression `(?:[^\/]*\/)*`
3. Replace last `.*` with `\S+`

Comment: Thx a million for the reply and fixes - greatly appreciated!